# Export all tables from an .accdb file programatically using Python

Tags: python, ms-access, win32com

I am trying to export all tables within an accdb file to csv. I am at the stage where I can export the table by calling out its name. Unfortunately, I need to do this in thousands of files, where I will not know the names of the tables ahead of time.

I am sure there is some sort of way to retrieve the name of the tables and then export them. I have the following code working, to export a table by calling out its name "TableX"

```
output = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop", 'Output.csv')
# OPEN ACCESS APP AND DATABASE
oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(accdbfile)

# EXPORT TABLE TO CSV
acExportDelim = 2
oApp.DoCmd.TransferText(TransferType=acExportDelim,
                            SpecificationName=None,
                            TableName="TableX",
                            FileName=output,
                            HasFieldNames=True)
#
oApp.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
oApp.Quit
oApp = None
```

Using the DoCmd command I am sure there is one such that it returns the names of all the tables which I then can just loop through. But unfortunately, I cannot find a way to obtain that. I know the following VBA code works within accdb to export all tables. But not sure how to integrate it with Python

```
Option Compare Database
Public Sub ExportAll()
Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
Set dbs = Application.CurrentData
In dbs.AllTables
    If Left(obj.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , obj.Name, _
           Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & obj.Name & ".csv", True
        'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
           obj.Name, Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & obj.Name & ".xls", True
    End If
Next obj
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open a recordset of table names from MSysObjects table

`SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE [Type]=1 AND NOT [Name] LIKE "*Sys*";`
That should limit to your data tables but I did notice an odd name in my db: f_38D36B8B99D54B1DB8E6D145B51ADF90_Data

2. then loop through the recordset
3. concatenate the [Name] field in the TransferText method

Or loop through TableDefs collection. Does the following help:

```
#sample code to list all tables in the selected database
 daoEngine = win32com.client.Dispatch('DAO.DBEngine.36')
 dtbs = daoEngine.OpenDatabase('database_file.mdb')
 for table in dtbs.TableDefs:
 if table.Name[:4] <> "MSys" and table.Name[:4] <> "~TMP":
```

Comment: When I try to implement the TableDefs I get the follwing: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'TableDefs`. Not sure why I cannot access the tables. Also, can you clarify what you meant by "open a recordset of tables names in MSyObject"

Comment: MSysObjects is a hidden system table that lists names of objects in the db. If you want to view the hidden tables, right click on Navigation Pane header > Navigaion Options > check Show System Objects. Python code was found and not tested.